# cubecamera in reflections

Tags: three.js

Gurus

Could you advice me how to do this: http://www.novaui.com/dc/insphere.png

this is a tetrahedral, and the faces reflect each other, and the ball reflect each other too, I can't make it same like the picture does by using cube camera, could you give me some clue?

Thanks,

Rosone

Answer (score 0):

You need raytracing for this. That's something that we can't easily do yet. NVIDIA was showing some raytracing in realtime in their new Kepler graphics card presentation some weeks ago.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h5mRRElXy-w

Comment: does three.js support raytracing?

Comment: Nope. It hasn't been implemented yet.